# Sum over subgroup in access report

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2007

I created an Access report that shows a listing of contracts with partners. I need the report to show the counting sum over groups and over subgroups. As this works quite well, I have to deal with a bug that I can't figure out:

[] is meant to be a textfield with it's name, setting and data content that I use to count over the groups.

() is meant to be a textfield that I use to present the result.

```
HEADER COUNTRY [txtCountCountryAll|sumoverall|=1]
    HEADER PARTNER [txtCountPartnerAll|sumoverall|=1] [txtCountPartnerGroup|sumovergroup|=1]
        DETAIL CONTRACT 1
        DETAIL CONTRACT 2
FOOTER COUNTRY (=txtCountPartnerGroup)

FOOTER REPORT (=txtCountPartnerAll) (=txtCountCountryAll)
```

Everything works fine except for the case that a country has EXACTLY two partners.

Than for some reason the "txtCountPartnerGroup" field of the first partner is not set to =1 as it is defined but is empty. The group count will be 1 instead of 2.

All overall sums will be correct anyway. The "txtCountPartnerAll" is set to =1 just fine in any case.

I made a screenshot with the txtFields set to visible. It shows the Textbox to be empty.

[image: Screenshot]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be comfortable using VBA code to calculate your subtotals? If so, Microsoft describes a solution where you calculate the subtotals yourself as each row is printed:

```
Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
  If PrintCount = 1 Then
    txtPageSum = txtPageSum + ExtendedPrice
    txtPageQuantity = txtPageQuantity + Quantity
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub PageHeaderSection_Print(Cancel As Integer, _
                                    PrintCount As Integer)
  txtPageSum = 0
  txtPageQuantity = 0
End Sub
```

The idea would be to add one to the partner count every time you print the partner footer. Every time you print the country header, you set the partner count to zero.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but I feel this might be a viable solution. One would think this is the way it is integrated when you try to achieve this via point&click.